# MS-DOS 32 bit mode Timer interrupt

Tags: disassembly, c++

My application works in 32 bit MS-DOS mode with dos4gw.exe extender. variables unknown_bool_0004AA8A = 1, unknown_bool_0004AAA0 = 1.

```
cseg01:0004AAB3                 mov     eax, offset Proc_Addr1
cseg01:0004AAB8                 push    eax
cseg01:0004AAB9                 push    0FFFFh
cseg01:0004AABE                 call    Timer_Interrupt_Controller
```

```
cseg01:000521C6 Timer_Interrupt_Controller proc near    ; CODE XREF: Interrupt_Controller_Proc+4Dp
cseg01:000521C6
cseg01:000521C6 arg_0_FFFF      = dword ptr  8
cseg01:000521C6 arg_4_Proc_Addr = dword ptr  0Ch
cseg01:000521C6
cseg01:000521C6                 push    ebp
cseg01:000521C7                 mov     ebp, esp
cseg01:000521C9                 push    esi
cseg01:000521CA                 push    edi
cseg01:000521CB                 push    ebx
cseg01:000521CC                 push    ecx
cseg01:000521CD                 push    fs
cseg01:000521CF                 push    gs
cseg01:000521D1                 push    es
cseg01:000521D2                 mov     edi, [ebp+arg_4_Proc_Addr]
cseg01:000521D5                 mov     Proc_Addr, edi
cseg01:000521DB                 mov     DS_word_000521DB, ds
cseg01:000521E2                 mov     DS_word_000521E2, ds
cseg01:000521E9                 cmp     unknown_bool_0004AAA0, 0
cseg01:000521F0                 jz      on_exit
cseg01:000521F6                 mov     dx, 21h ; '!'
cseg01:000521FA                 in      al, dx          ; Interrupt controller, 8259A.
cseg01:000521FB                 or      al, 1
cseg01:000521FD                 out     dx, al          ; Interrupt controller, 8259A.
cseg01:000521FE                 cmp     unknown_bool_0004AA8A, 0
cseg01:00052205                 jz      short condition_2
cseg01:00052207                 nop
cseg01:00052208                 nop
cseg01:00052209                 nop
cseg01:0005220A                 nop
cseg01:0005220B                 mov     ax, 204h
cseg01:0005220F                 mov     bl, 8
cseg01:00052211                 int     31h             ; DPMI Services   ax=func xxxxh
cseg01:00052211                                         ; GET PROTECTED MODE INTERRUPT VECTOR
cseg01:00052211                                         ; BL = interrupt number
cseg01:00052211                                         ; Return: CF set on error
cseg01:00052211                                         ; CF clear if successful, CX:DX / CX:EDX = selector:offset of handler
cseg01:00052213                 mov     Timer_offset_proc_addr, edx
cseg01:00052219                 mov     word ptr Timer_segment_proc_addr, cx
cseg01:00052220                 mov     ax, 205h
cseg01:00052224                 mov     bl, 8
cseg01:00052226                 mov     edx, offset Proc_Addr2
cseg01:0005222B                 mov     cx, cs
cseg01:0005222E                 int     31h             ; DPMI Services   ax=func xxxxh
cseg01:0005222E                                         ; SET PROTECTED MODE INTERRUPT VECTOR
cseg01:0005222E                                         ; BL = interrupt number, CX:DX / CX:EDX = selector:offset of handler
cseg01:0005222E                                         ; Return: CF set on error
cseg01:0005222E                                         ; CF clear if successful
cseg01:00052230                 jmp     short Timer
cseg01:00052230 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:00052232                 db 3 dup(90h)
cseg01:00052235 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:00052235
cseg01:00052235 condition_2:                            ; CODE XREF: Timer_Interrupt_Controller+3Fj
cseg01:00052235                 mov     ax, 3508h
cseg01:00052239                 int     21h             ; DOS - 2+ - GET INTERRUPT VECTOR
cseg01:00052239                                         ; AL = interrupt number
cseg01:00052239                                         ; Return: ES:BX = value of interrupt vector
cseg01:0005223B                 mov     Timer_offset_proc_addr, ebx
cseg01:00052241                 mov     word ptr Timer_segment_proc_addr, es
cseg01:00052248                 push    ds
cseg01:00052249                 xor     ax, ax
cseg01:0005224C                 mov     es, ax
cseg01:0005224E                 assume es:nothing
cseg01:0005224E                 mov     ax, 2508h
cseg01:00052252                 mov     edx, offset Proc_Addr2
cseg01:00052257                 push    cs
cseg01:00052258                 pop     ds
cseg01:00052259                 assume ds:nothing
cseg01:00052259                 int     21h             ; DOS - SET INTERRUPT VECTOR
cseg01:00052259                                         ; AL = interrupt number
cseg01:00052259                                         ; DS:DX = new vector to be used for specified interrupt
cseg01:0005225B                 pop     ds
cseg01:0005225C                 assume ds:dseg05
cseg01:0005225C
cseg01:0005225C Timer:                                  ; CODE XREF: Timer_Interrupt_Controller+6Aj
cseg01:0005225C                 mov     dx, 43h ; 'C'
cseg01:00052260                 mov     al, 36h ; '6'
cseg01:00052262                 out     dx, al          ; Timer 8253-5 (AT: 8254.2).
cseg01:00052263                 mov     dx, 40h ; '@'
cseg01:00052267                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0_FFFF]
cseg01:0005226A                 out     dx, al          ; Timer 8253-5 (AT: 8254.2).
cseg01:0005226B                 mov     al, ah
cseg01:0005226D                 out     dx, al          ; Timer 8253-5 (AT: 8254.2).
cseg01:0005226E                 mov     dx, 21h ; '!'
cseg01:00052272                 in      al, dx          ; Interrupt controller, 8259A.
cseg01:00052273                 and     al, 0FEh
cseg01:00052275                 out     dx, al          ; Interrupt controller, 8259A.
cseg01:00052276
cseg01:00052276 on_exit:                                ; CODE XREF: Timer_Interrupt_Controller+2Aj
cseg01:00052276                 pop     es
cseg01:00052277                 assume es:nothing
cseg01:00052277                 pop     gs
cseg01:00052279                 pop     fs
cseg01:0005227B                 pop     ecx
cseg01:0005227C                 pop     ebx
cseg01:0005227D                 pop     edi
cseg01:0005227E                 pop     esi
cseg01:0005227F                 pop     ebp
cseg01:00052280                 retn
cseg01:00052280 Timer_Interrupt_Controller endp
```

```
cseg01:00052119 Proc_Addr2      proc near               ; DATA XREF: Timer_Interrupt_Controller+60o
cseg01:00052119                                         ; Timer_Interrupt_Controller+8Co
cseg01:00052119                 push    ds
cseg01:0005211A                 call    __GETDS
cseg01:0005211A Proc_Addr2      endp
cseg01:0005211A
cseg01:0005211F ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:0005211F                 cmp     word_C7E3E, 1
cseg01:00052127                 jz      short loc_5217E
cseg01:00052129                 nop
cseg01:0005212A                 nop
cseg01:0005212B                 nop
cseg01:0005212C                 nop
cseg01:0005212D                 push    ax
cseg01:0005212F                 mov     ax, 20h ; ' '
cseg01:00052133                 out     20h, al         ; Interrupt controller, 8259A.
cseg01:00052135                 pop     ax
cseg01:00052137                 mov     word_C7E3E, 1
cseg01:00052140                 mov     dword ptr byte_C6E2E, esp
cseg01:00052146                 mov     word ptr byte_C6E2E+4, ss
cseg01:0005214D                 lss     esp, fword ptr off_C6E26
cseg01:00052154                 pusha
cseg01:00052155                 push    es
cseg01:00052156                 push    fs
cseg01:00052158                 push    gs
cseg01:0005215A                 push    ds
cseg01:0005215B                 pop     es
cseg01:0005215C                 assume es:dseg05
cseg01:0005215C                 mov     dword_C7E36, esp
cseg01:00052162                 call    Proc_Addr
cseg01:00052168                 pop     gs
cseg01:0005216A                 pop     fs
cseg01:0005216C                 pop     es
cseg01:0005216D                 assume es:nothing
cseg01:0005216D                 popa
cseg01:0005216E                 lss     esp, fword ptr byte_C6E2E
cseg01:00052175                 mov     word_C7E3E, 0
cseg01:0005217E
cseg01:0005217E loc_5217E:                              ; CODE XREF: cseg01:00052127j
cseg01:0005217E                 pop     ds
cseg01:0005217F                 iret
cseg01:00052180
```

```
cseg01:0004A840 __GETDS:                                ; CODE XREF: sub_481FE+Bp
cseg01:0004A840                                         ; Proc_Addr2+1p ...
cseg01:0004A840                 db      66h
cseg01:0004A840                 mov     ds, cs:word_4A849
cseg01:0004A848                 retn
cseg01:0004A848 start           endp
```

```
cseg01:0004B0CF Proc_Addr1      proc near               ; DATA XREF: Interrupt_Controller_Proc+42o
cseg01:0004B0CF
cseg01:0004B0CF var_4           = dword ptr -4
cseg01:0004B0CF
cseg01:0004B0CF                 push    ebx
cseg01:0004B0D0                 push    ecx
cseg01:0004B0D1                 push    edx
cseg01:0004B0D2                 push    esi
cseg01:0004B0D3                 push    edi
cseg01:0004B0D4                 push    ebp
cseg01:0004B0D5                 mov     ebp, esp
cseg01:0004B0D7                 sub     esp, 4
cseg01:0004B0DD                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0
cseg01:0004B0E4
cseg01:0004B0E4 loc_4B0E4:                              ; CODE XREF: Proc_Addr1+23j
cseg01:0004B0E4                 cmp     [ebp+var_4], 10h
cseg01:0004B0E8                 jb      short loc_4B0F4
cseg01:0004B0EA                 jmp     locret_4B168
cseg01:0004B0EF ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:0004B0EF
cseg01:0004B0EF loc_4B0EF:                              ; CODE XREF: Proc_Addr1:loc_4B166j
cseg01:0004B0EF                 inc     [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B0F2                 jmp     short loc_4B0E4
cseg01:0004B0F4 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:0004B0F4
cseg01:0004B0F4 loc_4B0F4:                              ; CODE XREF: Proc_Addr1+19j
cseg01:0004B0F4                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B0F7                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B0FA                 cmp     dword_C7FE4[eax], 0
cseg01:0004B101                 jz      short loc_4B166
cseg01:0004B103                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B106                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B109                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B10C                 shl     edx, 2
cseg01:0004B10F                 mov     edx, dword_C8064[edx]
cseg01:0004B115                 add     dword_C80A4[eax], edx
cseg01:0004B11B                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B11E                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B121                 test    byte ptr (dword_C80A4+2)[eax], 1
cseg01:0004B128                 jz      short loc_4B166
cseg01:0004B12A                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B12D                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B130                 mov     word ptr (dword_C80A4+2)[eax], 0
cseg01:0004B139                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B13C                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B13F                 cmp     byte_C80E4[eax], 0FFh
cseg01:0004B146                 jz      short loc_4B15A
cseg01:0004B148                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B14B                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B14E                 movzx   eax, byte_C80E4[eax]
cseg01:0004B155                 mov     dword_C8124, eax
cseg01:0004B15A
cseg01:0004B15A loc_4B15A:                              ; CODE XREF: Proc_Addr1+77j
cseg01:0004B15A                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0004B15D                 shl     eax, 2
cseg01:0004B160                 call    dword_C7FE4[eax]
cseg01:0004B166
cseg01:0004B166 loc_4B166:                              ; CODE XREF: Proc_Addr1+32j
cseg01:0004B166                                         ; Proc_Addr1+59j
cseg01:0004B166                 jmp     short loc_4B0EF
cseg01:0004B168 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:0004B168
cseg01:0004B168 locret_4B168:                           ; CODE XREF: Proc_Addr1+1Bj
cseg01:0004B168                 leave
cseg01:0004B169                 pop     edi
cseg01:0004B16A                 pop     esi
cseg01:0004B16B                 pop     edx
cseg01:0004B16C                 pop     ecx
cseg01:0004B16D                 pop     ebx
cseg01:0004B16E                 retn
cseg01:0004B16E Proc_Addr1      endp
```

How I understood, function Timer_Interrupt_Controller setup new interrupt function for timer. But I dont understand why this need? For me, need convert function Proc_Addr2 into C++ code with __asm statement. But I dont know how it to do. Who can assist me? Also I dont know what happens between label Timer: and label on_exit: - who can explain?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `what happens between label Timer: and label on_exit:` - setting timer parameters via I/O ports

Comment: Possible a bit detailed? What timer's parameters changes and for what? Quite normal timer - 18.2 ticks per second. What usage of this?

Comment: You can make the timer faster (for example, 1 kHz) to suit the needs of your application.  18.2 ticks is the minimum possible frequency (and this is exactly what your code does, `push 0FFFFh` before call is setting the minimum frequency).  One of a timer usage examples - generating sound of specified frequency by adjusting the settings of the corresponding timer.

Comment: This is information from 90s years MS DOS development. You took this from Internet or have own knowledge? Please share link, if possible, I want study this.

Comment: That's from my own memory, I wrote a lot of assembler programs for MSDOS.